# knockout dropdown list pass selection to model in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I am having a issue with a knockoutjs drop-down list, I have a MVC 5 application with this on my razor view, which is being bound from knockout.

```
<select name="alddlname" id="alddl" 
    data-bind="
        options: authorityLevel, 
        optionsText: 'AuthorityLevel', 
        optionsValue: 'aid', 
        value: aid
    ">
</select>
```

I would link to the use the selected item and pass it to a model attribute

```
public List<authorityLevel> authLevellistItems { get; set; }
public string SelectedAuthType { get; set; }
```

I would like to bind the model to the dropdown list so that selectedAuthType is then set to the value

the dropdown is poppulated from knockout with this

```
var authorityLevelList = Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.authorityLevelDDL));

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var vm = new AppViewModel();            
    vm.authorityLevel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@authorityLevelList);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Show some more of your code with specific details of an issue you are having or create an example of the issue in JSFiddle. There's not enough info here.

Comment: edited with extra c# code,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK so i have figured it out

if i use the `@html.DropDownListFor` helper and still bind my data attributes from knockout I have a DropDown list that is populated by knockout json array object, but then also bind this to the MVC 5 model this then can be passed back to a controller and inserted to a database.

//  the data_bind part is the knockout.js part the rest is the razor c# view helper

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedAuthType, 
        (SelectList)Model.authlevellistItems, 
new { id = "alddl", data_bind = " options: authorityLevel, optionsText: 'AuthorityLevel', optionsValue: 'aid'" })
```

hopefully this will help others and my question wasn't just a waste of time. 
Thanks A

Comment: Do you recall is the selectList you passed empty? this worked for me using `new List<SelectListItem>()` in place of your `(SelectList).Model.authlevellistItems` it seems that you would be binding once via MVC and again via knockout per your example. Am I correct? just trying to gain an understanding, not criticizing. thanks

Comment: As far as I remember - its been a while - I was using razor syntax on the load that this was MVC model bound and then after deals with all async via kncokout and json - your could probably not use razor and bind with  knockout on load and well as async